# Java: Sum of digits from String with Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, character

Example:
Input: abc565xyz
Output: 16
Which variant would be better? Thanks.

```
public static int sumOfDigits(String s) {
    return s.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).reduce(0, (i0, i1) -> i0 + Character.digit(i1, 10));
}

public static int sumOfDigits(String s) {
    return s.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).mapToObj(a -> a - '0').reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}

public static int sumOfDigits(String s) {
    return s.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).mapToObj(a -> Character.digit(a, 10)).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define better. What version of Java? Which release? Which platform are you planning on running it? In short, without testing it on the target platform it's very hard to say.

BTW, instead of `mapToObj` and an explicit `reduce`, it would be better to do

```
return s.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).map(a -> Character.digit(a, 10)).sum();
```

Mapping an `int` to an `Object` is probably the most expensive part and you did that in two of your versions. So, as posted, the first one is probably "best".

Comment: But the `reduce(0, (i0, i1) -> i0 + Character.digit(i1, 10))` of the first variant violates the associativity constraint.